# Base64_decode return string not exactly japanse character Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

When I try to convert string encode to decode string japanse character into IE with function `base64_decode`, it return string not exactly. My code very simple  like this :

```
$text = base64_encode('aサンプル.pdf');
echo base64_decode($text);
```

It's will print `a繧ｵ繝ｳ繝励Ν.pdf` only into IE and cakephp 2.0 .Chrome or FF working fine. In addition I try with the same code into codeigniter framework, it working fine too. What's wrong stay here. Please help!

Comment: Did you set the correct charset in <head>? i.e. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: else this could be due to some fixed character setting of IE browser in the menu "View-Encoding" or something like that. Did you compare the encoded strings in all browsers? do the look the same?

Comment: @Constantin GALBENU I really set `meta` for `head`.

Comment: @Alex Odenthal When I try to compare value, it's saying true. But the problem is string look not the same string.

Comment: and if you put the real string in ie it looks ok or is it screwed as well?

Comment: I has try and it's screwed. And when set encoding to UTF-8, it's showing up.

Comment: You should set the header for the response to UTF-8.

In cakephp2, you can do that using `$this->response->charset('utf-8')` in your controller.